# Handling exception on missing reference

Tags: vb.net, exception, filenotfoundexception

Is it possible to somehow in VB.NET to handle the exception that is thrown when a reference has not been copied into the correct directory. I was unable to find a way to include the DLL file for System.IO.SQLite into my application.

Currently if a user copies/installs only the exe file I get uncaught exception error due to the missing DLL file. I would like to gracefully explain the issue and then terminate the program, or at least give them an option to disable the SQLite portion of it.

Comment: Well, you don't have to worry much about the graceful termination.  Giving a reasonable diagnostic is something that every programmer should take care of, write an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event.  With the only stipulation that you must avoid using Sqlite in your Main() method.  Because that will bomb your program before you can register your event handler.  And put a bit of energy into an installer so this just can't go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any `Modules`, you need to remove any private/public declarations of that DLL. Then if you have a startup form, remove any private/public declarations of that DLL.

Every private/public declaration in a module of startup form is processed before your first line of code, so you cannot do that.

With the above done, you now can check to make sure the DLL existing in you directory doing something like this:

```
If Not IO.File.Exists("System.IO.SQLite.dll") then ...
```